# Multi-step model in one prediction with Keras LSTM

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, time-series, lstm

I am trying to do a river flow time-series prediction where given the precipitation and runoff data of the previous 5 days, I can predict the runoff data for the next 30 days. Currently, I have the prediction of all 30 days given in a single vector output. Right now my results are very different from the real data.

For creating my dataset, I had the time lags (var1(t-1), var2(t-1), var1(t-2)...var2(t-5)) for both features as the input and (t+29...t) as the output for only the runoff feature. For my data, I set the index to dates but that is lost when I convert them to numpy arrays, would having dates improve my results?

Here is the model I used:

```
fit = Sequential()
fit.add(LSTM(64, activation='tanh', return_sequences=True, recurrent_activation='hard_sigmoid', input_shape=(xtrain.shape[1], xtrain.shape[2])))
fit.add(LSTM(16, activation='relu'))
fit.add(Dense(n_predict))
```

I was able to receive results but they are not close at all, even the forecast near the beginning. From then on they usually have an overall linear trend while the actual data oscillates more. Is there anything I did wrong or anything I can improve?